# The message ”Failed to open session” is displayed when the DRM sample code is tested on HUAWEI P40

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I was testing the sample code on HUAWEI P40, and received the error message android.media.NotProvisionedException: Failed to open session. Any solution？Thanks for advance.

Comment: **What** sample code? You should include the relevant pieces of code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi，from what you described. The DRM service is not applied for or enabled.

Before integrating the DRM Kit, apply for integrating and enabling the DRM service. For details, see [How Do Developers Apply for and Enable DRM Kit](http://consumer-tkb.huawei.com/weknow/index.html#!a/detail.html?contextNo=en-us00931226)